# why dynamic Json isn't mapped to my class property values? and why retrieved Json invalid?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, facebook-c#-sdk

SO, I am trying to retrieve users feed likes for the first 25 records as below:

```
var access_token = HttpContext.Items["access_token"].ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(access_token))
            {
                var appsecret_proof = access_token.GenerateAppSecretProof();

                var fb = new FacebookClient(access_token);

               dynamic myFeed = await fb.GetTaskAsync(
                    ("me/feed?fields=likes{{name,pic_large}}")
//GraphAPICall formats the json retrieved from facebook
                        .GraphAPICall(appsecret_proof));

               string feed = myFeed;

                var postList = new List<FBAnalyseViewModel>();
                foreach (dynamic post in myFeed.data)
                {
                    postList.Add(DynamicExtension.ToStatic<FBAnalyseViewModel>(post));
                }
```

The `GraphAPI` above get the base `GraphAPICall` then formats the `Json` retrieved from facebook and appends the `appsecret_proof` plus arguments as here below:

```
 public static string GraphAPICall(this string baseGraphApiCall, params object[] args)
 {
      //returns a formatted Graph Api Call with a version prefix and appends a query string parameter containing the appsecret_proof value
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseGraphApiCall))
      {
          if (args != null &&
              args.Count() > 0)
          {
              //Determine if we need to concatenate appsecret_proof query string parameter or inject it as a single query string paramter
              string _graphApiCall = string.Empty;
              if (baseGraphApiCall.Contains("?"))
                  _graphApiCall = string.Format(baseGraphApiCall + "&appsecret_proof={" + (args.Count() - 1) + "}", args);
              else
                  _graphApiCall = string.Format(baseGraphApiCall + "?appsecret_proof={" + (args.Count() - 1) + "}", args);

                  //prefix with Graph API Version
                  return string.Format("v2.8/{0}", _graphApiCall);
              }
              else
                  throw new Exception("GraphAPICall requires at least one string parameter that contains the appsecret_proof value.");
        }
        else
            return string.Empty;
 }
```

I use an auto mapping technique for my property values as here below:

```
//Iterate through the dynamic Object's list of properties, looking for match from the facebook mapping lookup
        foreach (var entry in properties)
        {
        var MatchedResults = PropertyLookup.Where(x => x.facebookparent == entry.Key || x.facebookfield == entry.Key);

        if (MatchedResults != null)
            foreach (propertycontainer DestinationPropertyInfo in MatchedResults)
            {
                    object mappedValue =null;
                    if (entry.Value.GetType().Name == "JsonObject")
                    {
                        //drill down on level to obtain a list of properties from the child set of properties 
                        //of the dynamic Object
                        mappedValue = FindMatchingChildPropertiesRecursively(entry, DestinationPropertyInfo);                           

                        //child properity was not matched so apply the parent FacebookJson object as the entry value
                        if (mappedValue == null &&
                            DestinationPropertyInfo.facebookfield == entry.Key)
                            mappedValue = entry.Value;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DestinationPropertyInfo.facebookparent) &&
                            DestinationPropertyInfo.facebookfield == entry.Key)
                            mappedValue = entry.Value;
                    }

                    //copy mapped value into destination class property
                    if (mappedValue != null)
                        if (DestinationPropertyInfo.facebookMappedProperty.PropertyType.Name == "DateTime")
                        {
                            DestinationPropertyInfo.facebookMappedProperty.SetValue(entity, System.DateTime.Parse(mappedValue.ToString()), null);
                        }
                        else
                            DestinationPropertyInfo.facebookMappedProperty.SetValue(entity, mappedValue, null);
            }
    }
    return entity;
}
```

While in debugging mode I get null values on my model view properties just like below picture.
[image: Properties with null Values]
And the `Json` returned by facebook is also not a valid `json` in order to serialize/deserialize. Any workaround? Help please.

**EDIT:**
Model Values are mapped to facebook items are as follow:

```
[Required]
        [FacebookMapping("likes")]
        public dynamic Likes { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [FacebookMapping("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [FacebookMapping("pic_large")]
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
```

**Edit2:**
The `Json` retrieved from facebook `GrapAPICall` is as below:

```
{"data":[{"id":"1264038093655465_1274837905908817","likes":{"data":[{"name":"Sayed Zubair Hashimi","pic_large":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/14909900_10154513795037597_3241587822245799922_n.jpg?oh=54ead7e0ba74b45b632d96da1515ccf8&oe=591C4938","id":"10154729171332597"}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed `Json` that you provide is not valid, at least `]}}]}` was missed. After adding missing elements relevants objects look like as shown below:

```
public class PostDetail
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string pic_large { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Likes
{
    public List<PostDetail> data { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Likes likes { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Post> data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make a little bit explanation as far as I am new to C#. How can I implement this?

Comment: Think the lists are acting as wrappers to give you the additional brackets from what I can see.